# Deduping dataframe in R on one value, selecting any values of the other columns

Tags: r

imagine a df x:

```
name         value
tyler        1
tyler        2
jake         1
steph        3
```

I want to dedupe rows on name, but don't care which value of 'value' it comes with so that I get a resulting df of

```
name         value
tyler        [1 or 2, I dont care]
jake         1
steph        3
```

I have a unique identifier column I'd like distinct values of, and 18 other columns that I need one, any, value of.

Comment: `x = x[!duplicated(x$name), ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> x = x[!duplicated(x$name), ]

courtesy of bdemarest in a comment on my question

Answer (score 1):

You can try with: distinct from dplyr package.

```
distinct(x, name, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This will remove duplicated rows based on `name` from dataframe `x`. Per your request to return *any* value from the `value` column, use `.keep_all = TRUE`. The default of FALSE drops all columns other than the column(s) specified after the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

try `unique`:

```
x <- data.frame(name=c("tyler", "tyler", "jake", "steve"), value=c(1,3,4,6))
unique(x$name)
```

Comment: Right, but that will return unique names, and not the values of the other columns.